# Parsing JSON to build a hierarchy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse JSON data to build hierarchy categories and print them to a csv. I was hoping that someone could please help me.

JSON Data:

```
{"businessModelInfo":{"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":2,"description":"Platform for the security monitoring, detection & prevention of unauthorized access, misuse & modification to the enterprise network"},"id":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","name":"Network Security"},"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":212,"description":"Application security testing, vulnerability assessment & runtime application protection"},"id":"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43","name":"Application Security"},"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":55,"description":"Identity & Access Management (IAM) solution for the user login, authentication and authorization"},"id":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","name":"IAM"},"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d46":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":65,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for OAuth, SAML or XML based identity federation or SSO"},"id":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d46","name":"Federated Identity Management"},"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":177,"description":"Technologies, policies & controls deployed to protect data, applications, and the associated infrastructure of cloud computing"},"id":"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47","name":"Cloud Security"},"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":30,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for the cyber security of the enterprise owned endpoint devices"},"id":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","name":"Endpoint Security"},"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":124,"description":"Security for access to enterprise network & data by a non-company device"},"id":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","name":"BYOD Security"},"532ffec7e4b09e548233984f":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":5,"description":"Companies that provide an integrated Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS) for network security of SMB/SME or remote office"},"id":"532ffec7e4b09e548233984f","name":"NIDS"},"533008efe4b09e54823398bf":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":8,"description":"Companies that provide a platform to prevent cyber intrusion in the enterprise network"},"id":"533008efe4b09e54823398bf","name":"NIPS"},"53301ec6e4b09e54823399b4":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":33,"description":"Solution for detecting various cyber threats on enterprise owned and managed endpoint devices"},"id":"53301ec6e4b09e54823399b4","name":"Threat Detection"},"53303049e4b09e5482339a5b":{"parentId":"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43","nodeInfo":{"position":213,"description":"Companies that provide a vulnerability assessment platform for application modules, libraries & code"},"id":"53303049e4b09e5482339a5b","name":"Vulnerability Assessment"},"53303451e4b09e5482339a76":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":13,"description":"Companies that provide incident response solution for enterprise network from cyber attacks"},"id":"53303451e4b09e5482339a76","name":"Network Incident Response"},"53306594e4b09e5482339b74":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":134,"description":"Companies that provide solution for the assessment of device status, application installed and vulnerabilities detected over BYOD devices"},"id":"53306594e4b09e5482339b74","name":"Vulnerability Assessment"},"533065b0e4b09e5482339b75":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":132,"description":"Solution for the detection & remediation of malware including virus over BYOD devices"},"id":"533065b0e4b09e5482339b75","name":"Anti Malware"},"5330665de4b09e5482339b78":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":31,"description":"Unified threat management including threat response, vulnerability assessment and patch management"},"id":"5330665de4b09e5482339b78","name":"Endpoint UTM"},"5330677ae4b09e5482339b7a":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":36,"description":"Endpoint security for the protection against malware including computer viruses, worms, trojan horses, ransomware, spyware, adware, and scareware"},"id":"5330677ae4b09e5482339b7a","name":"Anti Malware"},"533067dfe4b09e5482339b7b":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":45,"description":"Companies that provide a whitelisting based execution of pre-determined and vetted application on endpoint"},"id":"533067dfe4b09e5482339b7b","name":"Application Whitelisting"},"5330697de4b09e5482339b7d":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":44,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to assess the vulnerability of endpoint system"},"id":"5330697de4b09e5482339b7d","name":"Vulnerability Assessment"},"533aabf1e4b02eaca1338cad":{"parentId":"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43","nodeInfo":{"position":226,"description":"Platform for crowdsourced testing of enterprise application for security bugs and exploits"},"id":"533aabf1e4b02eaca1338cad","name":"Crowdsourced Security Testing"},"53438e8ae4b03bb69fb23bd5":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":133,"description":"Companies that provide a mobile network access control for BYOD devices"},"id":"53438e8ae4b03bb69fb23bd5","name":"Mobile NAC"},"5344f426e4b092ee736cf843":{"parentId":"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47","nodeInfo":{"position":182,"description":"Companies that provide a security solution for a cloud-based application and software"},"id":"5344f426e4b092ee736cf843","name":"Cloud Application Security"},"53463741e4b092ee736cfc82":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":3,"description":"Companies that provide an unified threat management solution for network security of SMB/SME or remote office"},"id":"53463741e4b092ee736cfc82","name":"Network UTM"},"534d01afe4b059431aef8956":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":136,"description":"Companies that provide a solution for the protection of data at rest, in use & in-transit from unauthorized access & modification"},"id":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","name":"Data Security"},"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":200,"description":"Companies that provide security of websites and web services from an internet wide attack"},"id":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","name":"Website Security"},"5357acb3e4b095b7a9fcd924":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":14,"description":"Companies that provide Virtual Private Network (VPN) for a secure remote access to the interent."},"id":"5357acb3e4b095b7a9fcd924","name":"VPN"},"535928bce4b048998cb752d9":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":187,"description":"Security of users against fraud, identity theft, payment fraud & phone fraud"},"id":"535928bce4b048998cb752d9","name":"Anti Fraud"},"535de22ce4b0735cb1b3e164":{"parentId":"535928bce4b048998cb752d9","nodeInfo":{"position":188,"description":"Solution to detect and prevent digital identity theft"},"id":"535de22ce4b0735cb1b3e164","name":"Identity Theft"},"535e6460e4b0b029c534b1d3":{"parentId":"532ffec7e4b09e548233984f","nodeInfo":{"position":7,"description":"Companies that provide a decoy based intrusion detection and deception solution"},"id":"535e6460e4b0b029c534b1d3","name":"Honeypot"},"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":234,"description":"Actionable, processed, aggregated, relevant & evidence-based knowledge of existing & new threats & vulnerabilities"},"id":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","name":"Threat Intelligence"},"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc6":{"parentId":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","nodeInfo":{"position":236,"description":"Companies that provide a collaboration platform for updating, managing and sharing cyber threat intelligence to enterprises"},"id":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc6","name":"Enterprise Collaboration"},"5363a93de4b0bacf25f2ce00":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":159,"description":"Companies that provide Hardware Security Module (HSM) or HSM grade security to manage digital keys and perform cryptoprocessing"},"id":"5363a93de4b0bacf25f2ce00","name":"Hardware Security Module (HSM)"},"536cb875e4b0bb23233efcbd":{"parentId":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","nodeInfo":{"position":235,"description":"Companies that provide a platform and services which delivers threat intelligence feed"},"id":"536cb875e4b0bb23233efcbd","name":"Platform & Services"},"5371bca1e4b022d05fc6c31f":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":243,"description":"Companies that provide a secure gateway and encryption of email communication system"},"id":"5371bca1e4b022d05fc6c31f","name":"Email Security"},"5371e43be4b022d05fc6c47b":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":49,"description":"Companies that provide protection & control of a single Internet-connected endpoint from intruders"},"id":"5371e43be4b022d05fc6c47b","name":"Secure Gateway"},"53720cc7e4b022d05fc6c6a1":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":202,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for monitoring, vulnerability assessment & audit of websites"},"id":"53720cc7e4b022d05fc6c6a1","name":"Web Vulnerability Assessment"},"5373251ae4b0595dbe736774":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":153,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for big data security by classifying and enforcing access control"},"id":"5373251ae4b0595dbe736774","name":"Big Data Security"},"537329bfe4b0595dbe736785":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":96,"description":"Companies that provide a secure platform to generate and manage  secure password"},"id":"537329bfe4b0595dbe736785","name":"Password Manager"},"53734e55e4b071174050713b":{"parentId":"535928bce4b048998cb752d9","nodeInfo":{"position":194,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to detect, prevent and protect against phone fraud"},"id":"53734e55e4b071174050713b","name":"Phone Fraud"},"53748c18e4b085ec4f4d312f":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":46,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to secure endpoint by virtualizing and isolating the browsing activity for preventing web-based attacks"},"id":"53748c18e4b085ec4f4d312f","name":"Threat Isolation"},"5374be82e4b085ec4f4d342a":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":74,"description":"Companies that provide a biometrics-based IAM solution"},"id":"5374be82e4b085ec4f4d342a","name":"Biometrics"},"5374e1cae4b085ec4f4d3595":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":203,"description":"Solution which provide real time reputation of a domain to prevent or block cyber threat"},"id":"5374e1cae4b085ec4f4d3595","name":"Reputation Monitoring"},"5375f10be4b035e7ab6e9547":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":106,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for IAM governance and access intelligence"},"id":"5375f10be4b035e7ab6e9547","name":"Intelligence & Governance"},"53ccd374e4b0c99052489339":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":204,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for the detection of cyber threats in a website"},"id":"53ccd374e4b0c99052489339","name":"Threat Detection"},"53ff40d8e4b0785237e38b7c":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":205,"description":"Companies that detect and protect against DDoS attacks including layer 3,4 & 7"},"id":"53ff40d8e4b0785237e38b7c","name":"DDoS Mitigation"},"54071895e4b0fd800eb0005b":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":259,"description":"Companies that provide cybersecurity for Operations technology such as IACS & SCADA systems"},"id":"54071895e4b0fd800eb0005b","name":"Industrial Security"},"5412f794e4b0ff6e2b21fcd6":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":254,"description":"Security to protect data, identities, devices, IP and servers in the IOT"},"id":"5412f794e4b0ff6e2b21fcd6","name":"IoT Security"},"545cd365e4b0a2f443016b44":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":125,"description":"Companies that provide Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) including MDM, MAM, IAM and/or enterprise app store."},"id":"545cd365e4b0a2f443016b44","name":"EMM"},"55129e45e4b0fb7fb6ee3dc8":{"parentId":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","nodeInfo":{"position":240,"description":"Platform which assess and delivers quantitative score of an enterprise security and risk posture"},"id":"55129e45e4b0fb7fb6ee3dc8","name":"Security & Risk Scorecards"},"55c49718e4b055e17db8dd86":{"parentId":"52ff2e3de4b0b193ed664d4a","nodeInfo":{"position":34,"description":"Platform to detect and respond to cyber threat on endpoint devices"},"id":"55c49718e4b055e17db8dd86","name":"Incident Detection & Response"},"55d5799ce4b0ccb9ba3e7e20":{"parentId":"5371bca1e4b022d05fc6c31f","nodeInfo":{"position":244,"description":"Companies that provide a Secure Email Gateway (SEG) that prevents malicious or rogue email and attachment based on enterprise policy"},"id":"55d5799ce4b0ccb9ba3e7e20","name":"SEG"},"55d57fe4e4b0ccb9ba3e7f0c":{"parentId":"5371bca1e4b022d05fc6c31f","nodeInfo":{"position":250,"description":"Companies that provide anti-spam, email validation and email abuse detection platform"},"id":"55d57fe4e4b0ccb9ba3e7f0c","name":"Anti-Spam"},"55d58156e4b0ccb9ba3e7f2d":{"parentId":"5371bca1e4b022d05fc6c31f","nodeInfo":{"position":245,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to encrypt email communication and access control over mail"},"id":"55d58156e4b0ccb9ba3e7f2d","name":"Email Encryption"},"55d5a577e4b0ccb9ba3e8283":{"parentId":"53303049e4b09e5482339a5b","nodeInfo":{"position":221,"description":"Companies that provide a vulnerability assessment of open source modules, libraries and 3rd party application modules"},"id":"55d5a577e4b0ccb9ba3e8283","name":"Open Source Component"},"55d5a970e4b0ccb9ba3e8364":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":206,"description":"Security solution to prevent web scraping & malware execution through network of bots remotely controlled by C&C"},"id":"55d5a970e4b0ccb9ba3e8364","name":"Botnet Protection"},"55d5b9bee4b045fa07677822":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":59,"description":"Companies that provide a solution for the creation, management, control and security of privileged accounts and secrets"},"id":"55d5b9bee4b045fa07677822","name":"Privileged IAM"},"55dc20fae4b068a5fe11694a":{"parentId":"53564831e4b0411aaf48b159","nodeInfo":{"position":208,"description":"Companies that provide a digital certificate for validation of SSL implementation and trusted information exchange"},"id":"55dc20fae4b068a5fe11694a","name":"Digital Certificate"},"55e830d9e4b00337fcf9357f":{"parentId":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","nodeInfo":{"position":239,"description":"Platform & service which monitors entire web including dark web for detecting cyber threat and data breach"},"id":"55e830d9e4b00337fcf9357f","name":"Dark Net Monitoring"},"55ed82d7e4b0126850c78a4e":{"parentId":"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43","nodeInfo":{"position":222,"description":"Companies that provide a Runtime Application Self-Protection (RASP) solution to protect application by identifying and blocking attacks during runtime"},"id":"55ed82d7e4b0126850c78a4e","name":"RASP"},"560cf14be4b0e484a84b59a4":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":12,"description":"Companies that provide the security of DNS system/server/software"},"id":"560cf14be4b0e484a84b59a4","name":"DNS Security"},"5640ffcce4b0920113c70ff5":{"parentId":"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47","nodeInfo":{"position":180,"description":"Companies that provide Cloud Access Security Broker (CASB) tools that act as security gateways for data security, visibility, threat protection and compliance across cloud services"},"id":"5640ffcce4b0920113c70ff5","name":"CASB"},"564b1801e4b06b8515d7c77e":{"parentId":"5412f794e4b0ff6e2b21fcd6","nodeInfo":{"position":255,"description":"Companies that provide a platform to detect cyber threats and anomalous behavior in IoT infrastructure and application"},"id":"564b1801e4b06b8515d7c77e","name":"Anomaly Detection"},"5657edefe4b0442049273784":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":275,"description":"Security & hardening of the servers to prevent unauthorized access & vulnerability attack"},"id":"5657edefe4b0442049273784","name":"Server Security"},"566015afe4b04c3365bfb798":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":155,"description":"Companies that provide Digital Rights Management (DRM) of enterprise document and software"},"id":"566015afe4b04c3365bfb798","name":"Enterprise DRM"},"56607831e4b031f08d379f19":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":1,"description":"Platform that provide security across enterprise including data, infrastructure, access & employs intelligence & analytics"},"id":"56607831e4b031f08d379f19","name":"Suite"},"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":107,"description":"Analytics of security information, event & system for threat prevention, detection, mitigation across enterprise"},"id":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","name":"Security Analytics"},"566085cfe4b031f08d379f2a":{"parentId":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","nodeInfo":{"position":118,"description":"Companies that provide analytics based solutions for threat detection at enterprise IT level"},"id":"566085cfe4b031f08d379f2a","name":"Threat Detection"},"566085cfe4b031f08d379f2b":{"parentId":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","nodeInfo":{"position":110,"description":"Companies that provide a assessment and management of the enterprise-wide cyber-risk and vulnerabilities present"},"id":"566085cfe4b031f08d379f2b","name":"Cyber Risk & Vulnerability Assessment"},"5660938ee4b031f08d379f32":{"parentId":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","nodeInfo":{"position":108,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for Security Information and Event Management (SIEM)"},"id":"5660938ee4b031f08d379f32","name":"SIEM"},"5662bfeee4b05dae5f69796c":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":156,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for Data Loss Prevention (DLP) and unauthorized exfiltration outside the enterprise"},"id":"5662bfeee4b05dae5f69796c","name":"Data Loss Prevention (DLP)"},"56646606e4b05dae5f697ec1":{"parentId":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","nodeInfo":{"position":122,"description":"Companies that provide a cyber forensics platform to analyze previously captured data packets and reverse engineer"},"id":"56646606e4b05dae5f697ec1","name":"Cyber Forensics"},"56646bf4e4b05dae5f697ed1":{"parentId":"532ffec7e4b09e548233984f","nodeInfo":{"position":6,"description":"Companies that provide a real time intrusion detection based on network activity and bandwidth pattern"},"id":"56646bf4e4b05dae5f697ed1","name":"Network Traffic Analytics"},"56648cd6e4b05dae5f697f90":{"parentId":"52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a","nodeInfo":{"position":274,"description":"Companies that provide a solution for the access control, auditing, encryption, integrity controls and secure backup of a database"},"id":"56648cd6e4b05dae5f697f90","name":"Database Security"},"566509f2e4b0a6e97ece0ceb":{"parentId":"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47","nodeInfo":{"position":178,"description":"Security for virtual infrastructure such as public/private cloud, VM Server, Workload, Hypervisor, Container"},"id":"566509f2e4b0a6e97ece0ceb","name":"Cloud Infrastructure Security"},"56650ac9e4b030508478a794":{"parentId":"52ff2e13e4b0b193ed664d47","nodeInfo":{"position":184,"description":"Companies that provide cyber security solution for the virtualised software containers"},"id":"56650ac9e4b030508478a794","name":"Container Security"},"566584ace4b017eeb445a7fb":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":9,"description":"Companies that provide solutions which filters traffic between two or more networks based on security rules"},"id":"566584ace4b017eeb445a7fb","name":"Firewall"},"5666b3cce4b0e5adf67b82d0":{"parentId":"566085cfe4b031f08d379f2a","nodeInfo":{"position":119,"description":"Companies that provide security analytics like UEBA to detect threat initiated or already present inside enterprise network"},"id":"5666b3cce4b0e5adf67b82d0","name":"Insider Threat Detection"},"5667c368e4b0716ca7d54d6d":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":92,"description":"Companies that provide modules & technology solution for the implementation and management of IAM  system"},"id":"5667c368e4b0716ca7d54d6d","name":"Technology"},"56690a78e4b0a29d350871ba":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":126,"description":"Companies that provide Mobile Device Management (MDM) software that allows IT administrators to control, secure and enforce policies on smartphones, tablets and other endpoints."},"id":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871ba","name":"MDM"},"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bb":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":128,"description":"Mobile Application Management (MAM) solution by whitelisting, application catalogue & arbitrary injecting encryption code in app"},"id":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bb","name":"MAM"},"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bc":{"parentId":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871ba","nodeInfo":{"position":127,"description":"MDM solution which employs separate encrypted containers for personal & workspace on single device"},"id":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bc","name":"Workspace Containerization"},"56690ca0e4b09e473de73598":{"parentId":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bb","nodeInfo":{"position":131,"description":"Companies that provide a layer of security wrapping over apps to protect against attacks & data theft"},"id":"56690ca0e4b09e473de73598","name":"Application Wrapping"},"56690ca0e4b09e473de73599":{"parentId":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bb","nodeInfo":{"position":130,"description":"Companies that analyze and manage apps based on profiling as per enterprise policies"},"id":"56690ca0e4b09e473de73599","name":"Application Profiling"},"56690ca0e4b09e473de7359a":{"parentId":"56690a78e4b0a29d350871bb","nodeInfo":{"position":129,"description":"Solution for the remote access to app on a BYOD device running over a secure virtual mobile infrastructure (VMI)"},"id":"56690ca0e4b09e473de7359a","name":"Application Virtualization"},"566936b9e4b0ccc692309dc3":{"parentId":"5660842ae4b031f08d379f29","nodeInfo":{"position":121,"description":"Platform or service to respond & mitigate already detected threat incident in enterprise"},"id":"566936b9e4b0ccc692309dc3","name":"Incident Response"},"566dbff1e4b0ac980bffaee1":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d46","nodeInfo":{"position":66,"description":"Companies that provide a Single Sign-On (SSO) solution to log in  on web & mobile sites and applications"},"id":"566dbff1e4b0ac980bffaee1","name":"SSO"},"566ecc97e4b087555e724e26":{"parentId":"5412f794e4b0ff6e2b21fcd6","nodeInfo":{"position":257,"description":"Companies that provide an embedded hardware or a software development kit for the IoT security"},"id":"566ecc97e4b087555e724e26","name":"Embeddable IoT Security"},"568eb20fe4b04d1ab768d5a7":{"parentId":"52ff2e04e4b0b193ed664d45","nodeInfo":{"position":56,"description":"Companies that provide a unified identity and access management solution"},"id":"568eb20fe4b04d1ab768d5a7","name":"Unified IAM"},"56a9b573e4b0079795f189f1":{"parentId":"52ff2df2e4b0b193ed664d43","nodeInfo":{"position":225,"description":"Security of API & API servers from attacks like denial of services, heartbleed, logjam, poodle etc"},"id":"56a9b573e4b0079795f189f1","name":"API Security"},"56bd9b65e4b0167a5f0ba8d8":{"parentId":"535de22ce4b0735cb1b3e164","nodeInfo":{"position":191,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to verify ID document digitally to prevent cyber fraud"},"id":"56bd9b65e4b0167a5f0ba8d8","name":"ID Document Verification"},"56d97b2ce4b096207eeba95e":{"parentId":"54071895e4b0fd800eb0005b","nodeInfo":{"position":260,"description":"Companies that provide vulnerability assessment of industrial cybersecurity posture"},"id":"56d97b2ce4b096207eeba95e","name":"Vulnerability Assessment"},"56d98df2e4b064ac7d89fe9f":{"parentId":"54071895e4b0fd800eb0005b","nodeInfo":{"position":261,"description":"Companies that provide a platform to detect cyber threats in the operational technology network including ICS & SCADA systems"},"id":"56d98df2e4b064ac7d89fe9f","name":"Threat Detection"},"56d9b8d2e4b064ac7d8a0a46":{"parentId":"54071895e4b0fd800eb0005b","nodeInfo":{"position":262,"description":"Companies that provide a solution to prevent cyber attacks on industrial systems including OT network, ICS/SCADA systems"},"id":"56d9b8d2e4b064ac7d8a0a46","name":"Threat Prevention"},"570b68d5e4b0b544cd006a5e":{"parentId":"5657edefe4b0442049273784","nodeInfo":{"position":276,"description":"Companies that provide security solution for operating system of server"},"id":"570b68d5e4b0b544cd006a5e","name":"OS Security"},"571742c7e4b0aafdf9f3a700":{"parentId":"5374be82e4b085ec4f4d342a","nodeInfo":{"position":77,"description":"Companies that provide an authentication platform based on innate human features like a fingerprint, iris pattern etc."},"id":"571742c7e4b0aafdf9f3a700","name":"Physiological"},"571742c7e4b0aafdf9f3a701":{"parentId":"5374be82e4b085ec4f4d342a","nodeInfo":{"position":75,"description":"Companies that provide an authentication platform based on identifying and confirming measurable patterns in human activities"},"id":"571742c7e4b0aafdf9f3a701","name":"Behavioral"},"5732f379e4b0bd8b59fc4788":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":25,"description":"Companies that provide Network Access Control (NAC) solution for controlled access to the internal network"},"id":"5732f379e4b0bd8b59fc4788","name":"Network Access Control"},"574fdd9ae4b0f0e47ea4f63d":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":160,"description":"Companies that provide a solution for data security and privacy by tokenization and obfuscation"},"id":"574fdd9ae4b0f0e47ea4f63d","name":"Data Masking"},"575ab8f7e4b0cb636486739f":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":137,"description":"Companies that provide security of data stored or moving through cloud-based storage"},"id":"575ab8f7e4b0cb636486739f","name":"Cloud Data Security"},"57763800e4b038d315f6c6a2":{"parentId":"534d01afe4b059431aef8956","nodeInfo":{"position":162,"description":"Companies that provide a software to erase & destroy data stored in digital storage system to prevent unauthorized access"},"id":"57763800e4b038d315f6c6a2","name":"Data Shredding"},"57835e1fe4b05105dcebe4c4":{"parentId":"53639ca0e4b0c0a1efec7cc5","nodeInfo":{"position":242,"description":"Companies that provide a platform for cybersecurity professionals and companies to discuss and share knowledge"},"id":"57835e1fe4b05105dcebe4c4","name":"Professional Community"},"578c659be4b026bca5a71887":{"parentId":"53295f48e4b07f1af3220cb0","nodeInfo":{"position":135,"description":"Companies that provide a software tools to perform digital forensics of mobile devices"},"id":"578c659be4b026bca5a71887","name":"Mobile Forensics"},"57cf9938e4b05893635e6100":{"parentId":"52ff2dd1e4b0b193ed664d41","nodeInfo":{"position":26,"description":"Companies that provide a Secure Web Gateway (SEG) to defend enterprise users from the Internet-borne threats"},"id":"57cf9938e4b05893635e6100","name":"SWG"},"57e51eb4e4b0e6e088ef96bb":{"parentId":"5330677ae4b09e5482339b7a","nodeInfo":{"position":37,"description":"Companies that provide an endpoint software to prevent, detect and remove malicious infections on end point devices"},"id":"57e51eb4e4b0e6e088ef96bb","name":"Antivirus"},"57e8ed37e4b03287ee8979a2":{"parentId":"53303049e4b09e5482339a5b","nodeInfo":{"position":216,"description":"Companies that provide a Static Application Security Testing (SAST) platform"},"id":"57e8ed37e4b03287ee8979a2","name":"SAST"}
```

I am able to print out all the names, ids, and parentIds with the following code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\UserName\CodeProjects\project_one\test.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())    
    idkeys = re.findall("'id': '(.*?)', 'name'", str(data))

  for idkey in idkeys:
    name = "Name: " + data['businessModelInfo'][idkey]['name']
    idd = "id: " + data['businessModelInfo'][idkey]['id']
    parent = "Parent: " + data['businessModelInfo'][idkey]['parentId']
    print(name)
    print(idd)
    print(parent)
```

I think I need to do a for loop to match the parentIds with their children Ids, but I have no idea where to begin.

Example desired output:

```
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Network UTM
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Secure Access Service Edge as a convergence (SASE)
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS > Network Traffic Analytics
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS > Network Traffic Analytics
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS > Honeypot
Cybersecurity > Network Security > VPN > Business VPN
Cybersecurity > Network Security > VPN > Personal VPN
Cybersecurity > Network Security > VPN > Personal VPN > Decentralized VPN
Cybersecurity > Network Security > VPN > Whitelabel VPN
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is truncated, and is missing the top-level node, but this supplies it and does what you ask. Basically, this is building a simple tree.

```
import json

data = json.load(open('x.json'))

class Node:
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.id = dct['id']
        self.name = dct['name']
        self.parent = dct['parentId']
        self.children = []

def insert( tree, node ):
    if tree.id == node.parent:
        tree.children.append( node )
        return True
    for n in tree.children:
        if insert( n, node ):
            return True

def traverse( tree, pfx='' ):
    pfx = tree.name if not pfx else ' '.join((pfx, '>', tree.name))
    print( pfx )
    for n in tree.children:
        traverse( n, pfx )

tree = Node(
    {
        'id': "52ff2cfce4b0b193ed664d1a",
        'name': 'Cybersecurity',
        'parentId': None
    }
)
for k,v in data['businessModelInfo'].items():
    if not insert( tree, Node(v) ):
        print( v, "location not found" )

traverse( tree )
```

Output:

```
Cybersecurity
Cybersecurity > Network Security
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS > Honeypot
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIDS > Network Traffic Analytics
Cybersecurity > Network Security > NIPS
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Network Incident Response
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Network UTM
Cybersecurity > Network Security > VPN
Cybersecurity > Network Security > DNS Security
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Firewall
Cybersecurity > Network Security > Network Access Control
Cybersecurity > Network Security > SWG
Cybersecurity > Application Security
Cybersecurity > Application Security > Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > Application Security > Vulnerability Assessment > Open Source Component
Cybersecurity > Application Security > Vulnerability Assessment > SAST
Cybersecurity > Application Security > Crowdsourced Security Testing
Cybersecurity > Application Security > RASP
Cybersecurity > Application Security > API Security
Cybersecurity > IAM
Cybersecurity > IAM > Federated Identity Management
Cybersecurity > IAM > Federated Identity Management > SSO
Cybersecurity > IAM > Password Manager
Cybersecurity > IAM > Biometrics
Cybersecurity > IAM > Biometrics > Physiological
Cybersecurity > IAM > Biometrics > Behavioral
Cybersecurity > IAM > Intelligence & Governance
Cybersecurity > IAM > Privileged IAM
Cybersecurity > IAM > Technology
Cybersecurity > IAM > Unified IAM
Cybersecurity > Cloud Security
Cybersecurity > Cloud Security > Cloud Application Security
Cybersecurity > Cloud Security > CASB
Cybersecurity > Cloud Security > Cloud Infrastructure Security
Cybersecurity > Cloud Security > Container Security
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Threat Detection
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Endpoint UTM
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Anti Malware
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Anti Malware > Antivirus
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Application Whitelisting
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Secure Gateway
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Threat Isolation
Cybersecurity > Endpoint Security > Incident Detection & Response
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > Anti Malware
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > Mobile NAC
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > EMM
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MDM
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MDM > Workspace Containerization
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MAM
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MAM > Application Wrapping
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MAM > Application Profiling
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > MAM > Application Virtualization
Cybersecurity > BYOD Security > Mobile Forensics
Cybersecurity > Data Security
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Hardware Security Module (HSM)
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Big Data Security
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Enterprise DRM
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Data Loss Prevention (DLP)
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Data Masking
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Cloud Data Security
Cybersecurity > Data Security > Data Shredding
Cybersecurity > Website Security
Cybersecurity > Website Security > Web Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > Website Security > Reputation Monitoring
Cybersecurity > Website Security > Threat Detection
Cybersecurity > Website Security > DDoS Mitigation
Cybersecurity > Website Security > Botnet Protection
Cybersecurity > Website Security > Digital Certificate
Cybersecurity > Anti Fraud
Cybersecurity > Anti Fraud > Identity Theft
Cybersecurity > Anti Fraud > Identity Theft > ID Document Verification
Cybersecurity > Anti Fraud > Phone Fraud
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence > Enterprise Collaboration
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence > Platform & Services
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence > Security & Risk Scorecards
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence > Dark Net Monitoring
Cybersecurity > Threat Intelligence > Professional Community
Cybersecurity > Email Security
Cybersecurity > Email Security > SEG
Cybersecurity > Email Security > Anti-Spam
Cybersecurity > Email Security > Email Encryption
Cybersecurity > Industrial Security
Cybersecurity > Industrial Security > Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > Industrial Security > Threat Detection
Cybersecurity > Industrial Security > Threat Prevention
Cybersecurity > IoT Security
Cybersecurity > IoT Security > Anomaly Detection
Cybersecurity > IoT Security > Embeddable IoT Security
Cybersecurity > Server Security
Cybersecurity > Server Security > OS Security
Cybersecurity > Suite
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > Threat Detection
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > Threat Detection > Insider Threat Detection
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > Cyber Risk & Vulnerability Assessment
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > SIEM
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > Cyber Forensics
Cybersecurity > Security Analytics > Incident Response
Cybersecurity > Database Security
```

One might consider keeping the children lists sorted.

Comment: Holy SMOKES Tim! You're awesome! One last question: how would I export all this into a csv? I can't thank you enough.

Comment: What would you put in a CSV?  The number of "fields" here varies.  If you just want this written to a text file, add an "outfile" parameter to `traverse`, and do `print( pfx, file=outfile )`.

Comment: Awesome. One last thing came to mind. I need to have the description at the end for the last child. If you can help me figure that out, my work will be done, and you'll be legend rivaled by the gods.

Comment: They all have descriptions.  Why would you only treat the leaf nodes differently?  You can identify those in `traverse` by doing `if  not tree.children:`.